# (software-properties-gtk) double running in the same OS. Is it a problem?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center, software-installation

I am new here :) and starting studies. I found 2 files with the same name on the software center of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS generic.

Is it normal?

Comment: @Manisha: Please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/498331/revisions).  Don't just delete stuff, but check the spelling and grammar of questions/Answers as well!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Use CTRL + ALT + T or open a terminal and type the following command

```
dpkg -l | grep software-properties-gtk
```

The output should look something like this

```
ii  software-properties-gtk     0.92.28         all          manage the repositories that 
you install software from (gtk)
```

Explained

`dpkg -l` lists installed packages and adding `| grep` tells the computer to only list results matching what is specified. If there are two of the same program installed, it will be listed twice. The sample output above only shows the program is only listed one time.

On my computer, I have the following files for this program and this is normal

```
/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk 
/usr/bin/X11/software-properties-gtk 
/usr/share/man/man1/software-properties-gtk.1.gz
```

Comment: I used the command `whereis software-properties-gtk` to show which files are on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Hy mchid
Thanks the attention.
I made that and it run, but the program center still showing the double arquives. Whould You please see the photo :) [this image is of program center on this OS Ubuntu 14.04 lts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFqlu.png)
Best regards
[]s